# How to run a Set-ProcessMitigation PowerShell cmdlet in Inno Setup Run section

Tags: powershell, installation, inno-setup

I want to run some commands in PowerShell after my Inno Setup install.

But at the end it or shows the command without running or show the term error.

```
[Run]                                                                                                                                                                              
Filename: "powershell.exe"; Parameters: "-NoProfile -NoExit -Command ""& {{Set-ProcessMitigation -Name ""{app}\Game.exe"" -Disable BottomUp}"""; StatusMsg: "Configurando..."; Description: "Configurando..."; Flags: shellexec
Filename: "powershell.exe"; Parameters: "Set-ProcessMitigation -Name ""{app}\Game.exe"" -Disable HighEntropy"; StatusMsg: "Configurando..."; WorkingDir: {app}; Description: "Configurando..."; Flags: shellexec    
Filename: "powershell.exe"; Parameters: "Set-ProcessMitigation -Name ""{app}\Game.exe"" -Disable ForceRelocateImages"; StatusMsg: "Configurando..."; WorkingDir: {app}; Description: "Configurando..."; Flags: shellexec
```

at the first one I'm trying some but without success, the command is simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There are more issues in your script. I'll address the `Set-ProcessMitigation` part now.*

For some reason the [`Set-ProcessMitigation` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/processmitigations/set-processmitigation) seems to be available in 64-bit PowerShell only. As Inno Setup is a 32-bit application, it will run 32-bit PowerShell by default. So the cmdlet is not found.

To make Inno Setup run 64-bit PowerShell, add [`64bit` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=64bit) to the `[Run]` section entry. Also `64bit` flag cannot be combined with [`shellexec` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=shellexec). But I do not think you really need that, so remove the `shellexec` flag.

```
[Run]
Filename: "powershell.exe"; \
  Parameters: "-NoProfile -NoExit -Command ""Set-ProcessMitigation ..."""; Flags: 64bit
```